# How to rate in full star android in Ratting Bar?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is xml code;

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:max="5"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red" />
```

ratingbar_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/mark_as_favorite_star_grey" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/mark_as_favorite_star_half" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/mark_as_favorite_star_full" />
```

Comment: Does  `android:stepSize="1.0"` not worked ?

Comment: show `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red"`

Comment: Hii @ADM . Its not work properly. If I click on 2nd number star it fills 3rd star. I want if 2nd star is already filled then it will unfill & if it unfill then it will fill

Comment: @vishal (connection phase)- once try without using android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red"

Answer (score 0):

it not possible in `RatingBar` because  `RatingBar` is an extension of `SeekBar` and `ProgressBar` that shows a rating in stars. The user can **touch/drag** or use arrow keys to set the rating when using the default size `RatingBar` , as per ypur requirement you need to make custom ratingbar using `imageButton` or `imageview` which you want to use with `TouchListener`

But is not good way as RatingBar, When using a RatingBar that supports user interaction, placing widgets to the left or right of the RatingBar is discouraged

The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout) will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

for more info you may follow [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar)